# Newbie - "class in class" in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm quite new to React and a little stuck. Could someone please explain me how to achieve the following?

I have a child class, something like

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class testClass extends React.Component {
    render() {
    const {fields} = this.props;

    return (
        <Text>
        blafasel
        </Text>
        )
    }
}
```

and a parent class like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import testClass from './TestClass';

class testParentClass extends React.Component {
render() {
    const {fields} = this.props;

    return (
        ---> display testClass here
    );
}
```

hope you get the idea. Is this possible? I think so. But how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do it the same way you did with `Text`:

```
return (
    <testClass />
);
```

**But:** Note that React component class names [must be initially-capped](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized) (and in any case, it's the overwhelming convention in JavaScript to capitalize class names / constructor function names). So `TestClass` and `TestParentClass` rather than `testClass` and `testParentClass`, and then in `TestParentClass`'s `render`:

```
return (
    <TestClass />
);
```

Comment: Hi T. J., thanks, that did the trick. Didn't expect it to be that easy :)